# C# Same methods for different argument type

Tags: c#, refactoring, readability

I have this inteface:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    bool Execute(Vector2 commandPosition);
    bool Execute(GameUnit gameUnit);
    bool Execute(string shortcut);
}
```

And a class with these methods making same things with different argument types

```
private void DispatchGameUnitCommand(GameUnit gameUnit)
{
    if (_preparedCommand != null)
    {
        _preparedCommand.Execute(gameUnit);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _commands.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_commands[i].Execute(gameUnit))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void DispatchLocationCommand(Vector2 screenPosition)
{
    if (_preparedCommand != null)
    {
        _preparedCommand.Execute(screenPosition);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _commands.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_commands[i].Execute(screenPosition))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void DispatchShortcutCommand(string shortcut)
{
    if (_preparedCommand != null)
    {
        _preparedCommand.Execute(shortcut);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _commands.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_commands[i].Execute(shortcut))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

How could I improve them removing duplicated code? Is it possible in anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Your post says you have "a class with these methods" for `GameUnit`, `Vector2` and `string`.

All indications in your code sample are that an actual `GameUnit` is required to *do* anything. In this case, the thing that "might" really help is having [implicit conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) that turn a `string` or a `Vector2` into a `GameUnit`.

---

**`GameUnit` with implicit conversions**

```
public class GameUnit
{
    public Vector2 Vector2 { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public static Dictionary<string, GameUnit> Shortcuts { get; }
        = new Dictionary<string, GameUnit>();

    public static implicit operator GameUnit(Vector2 vector)
    {
        return new GameUnit { Vector2 = vector };
    }

    public static implicit operator GameUnit(string shortcut)
    {
        Shortcuts.TryGetValue(shortcut, out GameUnit gameUnit);
        return gameUnit; // Will be null if not in dict
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Vector2} {Name}";
}
```

Following this logic, we end up with a dispatcher class that needs only *one* method not three.

```
public class Dispatcher
{
    public void DispatchGameUnitCommand(GameUnit context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Dispatching {context}");
    }
}
```

As for the `interface`, how were you planning on using it? So far, it's not needed for anything.

---

**Testing**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "GameUnit Test";
    Dispatcher exec = new Dispatcher();
    GameUnit
        adHoc = new GameUnit { Name = "AdHoc", Vector2 = new Vector2(5000, 2000) },
        vectorA = new GameUnit { Name = "VectorA", Vector2 = new Vector2(5, 20) };
    GameUnit.Shortcuts[adHoc.Name] = adHoc;
    GameUnit.Shortcuts[vectorA.Name] = vectorA;

    exec.DispatchGameUnitCommand(adHoc);
    exec.DispatchGameUnitCommand("VectorA");
    exec.DispatchGameUnitCommand(new Vector2(500, 200));
}
```

[image: console output]

Comment: As an aside, consider renaming `ICommand` to something (anything) else. It's likely to cause massive conflicts with `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` going forward.